# How to create a stacked barchart for a large dataset in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

For research purposes at my university, I need to create a stacked bar chart for speech data. I would like to represent the hours of speech on the y-axis and the frequency on the x-axis. The speech comes from different components, hence the stacked part of the chart. The data resides in a Pandas dataframe, which has a lot of columns, but the important ones are "component", "hours" and "ps_med_frequency" which are used in the graph.

A simplified view of the DF (it has 6.2k rows and 120 columns, a-k components):

| component | filename | ps_med_freq (rounded to integer) | hours (length) | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | fn0001_ps | 230 | 0.23 |  |
| b | fn0002_ps | 340 | 0.12 |  |
| c | fn003_ps | 278 | 0.09 |  |

I have already tried this with matplotlib, seaborn or just the plot method from the Pandas dataframe itself. None seem to work properly.

A snippet of seaborn code I have tried:

```
sns.barplot(data=meta_dataframe, x='ps_med_freq', y='hours', hue='component', dodge=False)
```

And basically all variations of this as well.

Below you can see one of the most "viable" results I've had so far:
[example of failed graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqNll.png)

It seems to have a lot of inexplicable grey blobs, which I first contributed to the large dataset, but if I just plot it as a histogram and count the frequencies instead of showing them by hour, it works perfectly fine. Does anyone know a solution to this?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: Yes, I realise this is a huge dataset and at first sight, the graph seems useless with that much data on it, but matplotlib has interactive graphs where you can zoom etc., where this kind of graph becomes useful for my purpose.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide example code / structure of the df, then is it easier to help

Comment: @Servus I added an example DF to my question :)

Comment: @JohanC My goal was indeed to visualise the number of hours I have per frequency. I could be wrong here, but doesn't a histogram only show the count? It is very important I don't "count" the frequencies but show how many hours of each I have. Good to know that the `sns.barplot` is not what I'm looking for, and I assume that the transparency explains the grey blobs then. I assume I should create something myself in matplotlib then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `sns.barplot` you're creating a bar for each individual frequency value. You'll probably want to group similar frequencies together, as with `sns.histplot(..., multiple='stack')`. If you want a lot of detail, you can increase the number of bins for the histogram. Note that `sns.barplot` never creates stacks, it would just plot each bar transparently on top of the others.

You can create a histogram, using the hours as weights, so they get summed.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create some suitable random test data
np.random.seed(20230104)
component_prob = np.random.uniform(0.1, 2, 7)
component_prob /= component_prob.sum()
df = pd.DataFrame({'component': np.random.choice([*'abcdefg'], 6200, p=component_prob),
                   'ps_med_freq': (np.random.normal(0.05, 1, 6200).cumsum() + 200).astype(int),
                   'hours': np.random.randint(1, 39, 6200) * .01})

# create bins for every range of 10, suitably rounded, and shifted by 0.001 to avoid floating point roundings
bins = np.arange(df['ps_med_freq'].min() // 10 * 10 - 0.001, df['ps_med_freq'].max() + 10, 10)
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 5))
ax = sns.histplot(data=df, x='ps_med_freq', weights='hours', hue='component', palette='bright',
                  multiple='stack', bins=bins)
# sns.move_legend(ax, loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 1.01)) # legend outside
sns.despine()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.histplot using weights]